# python turn these print values into dictionary with keys being first column and the buttom being dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working with django and got back a response that looks like this

```
Name,surname
AVA,AAJ
DAA2,ASA
EAA23,VVD
GAA43,DDA
AAA42,AAS
MAA21,JJ
```

produced by this code

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def testfunc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        print(x)
        return JsonResponse(x,safe=False)
```

i want to place this into a dictionary with the first row being the key and the remaining rows being the values, so they can be further processed.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the dictionary to look like?

Comment: @LiorDahan thanks for the response

e.g.

{ Name:"AVA",surname:"AAJ"},{ Name:"DAA2",surname:"ASA"}

Answer (score 0):

You need to first split the text in lines and then split words in each line.

Something like this:

```py
lines = x.strip().split("\n")
keys = lines[0].split(",")
users_list = []
for line in lines[1:]:
    d = dict()
    for i, val in enumerate(line.strip().split(",")):
        d[keys[i]] = val
    users_list.append(d)
```

example output:

```
>>> print(users_list)
[{'Name': 'AVA', 'surname': 'AAJ'}, {'Name': 'DAA2', 'surname': 'ASA'}, {'Name': 'EAA23', 'surname': 'VVD'}, {'Name': 'GAA43', 'surname': 'DDA'}, {'Name': 'AAA42', 'surname': 'AAS'}, {'Name': 'MAA21', 'surname': 'JJ'}]
```